# Datamapper type for char (aka character) field type

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, orm, ruby-datamapper

I'm working with an open source database. I'm trying to map it to classes with DataMapper, and later I'm going to make changes in a Model driven approximation instead of a Database driven one.

But first I would like to map the open source database in an exact way. This database is a PostgreSQL one and in some tables there are some fields with a `character` type.

How can I map `character` type in DataMapper? This type it's not in its [primitive types](http://rubydoc.info/github/datamapper/dm-core/master/DataMapper/Property), nor in [`dm-types`](http://datamapper.org/docs/dm_more/types.html), nor in [`dm-types-legacy`](https://github.com/postmodern/dm-types-legacy/).

If it gives more information, actually I'm not writing the model by hand but I'm using [`dm-is-reflective`](https://github.com/godfat/dm-is-reflective), which automatically maps an existing database table. It gives me following error:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-is-reflective-1.0.0/lib/dm-is-reflective/is/adapters/data_objects_adapter.rb:141:in `reflective_lookup_primitive': bpchar not found for DataMapper::Adapters::PostgresAdapter (TypeError)
```

**EDIT**
It was a problem with `dm-is-reflective` and not with `datamapper` core, which can work well with `char` type as a `String` type with a length set. I answer with the solution to the problem.

Comment: Can you change those fields to `varchar` or (better) `text`? In PostgreSQL, `char` is usually a bad choice for a data type.  It is supported because it is in the standard, but it would be wise to avoid using it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @kgrittn. But as I said I would like to do a mapping to the original and intact database, and from there make my changes with the models as bases...

Comment: I guess you need to find a gem which deals with this archaic data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

godfat, the man working in `dm-is-reflective` quickly solved this issue :) Many thanks to him!

https://github.com/godfat/dm-is-reflective/issues/3#issuecomment-5726650